# Passing variable from JavaScript to PHP using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am giving the user a possibility to comment, when he comments I would like that comment to be saved in my database. I will take care of the saving to database part, but I need help with passing the text input from JavaScript to PHP. I would like to simply echo the 'imeBoxa' and 'komentar' variables. My problem is inside the ajax function.

HTML within index.php:

```
<button class="pointer comment">Komentiraj</button>

<script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl" id="fieldTemplate2"/>
<p><div class="imeBoxa"><b>{{imeBoxa}}</b>:</div> {{komentar}}</p>
<hr/>
</script>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#leftColumn").on("click", ".comment",function()
    {
        var imeBoxa = prompt("Komentar za vijest:","");
        var komentar = prompt("Komentar","");

        if(komentar != null && imeBoxa != null)
        {
            var fieldTemplate2 = $("#fieldTemplate2").text();

            fieldTemplate2 = fieldTemplate2.replace("{{imeBoxa}}", imeBoxa);
            fieldTemplate2 = fieldTemplate2.replace("{{komentar}}", komentar);

            $.ajax
            ({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'index.php',
                data:
                {
                    imeBoxa,
                    komentar
                },
                success: function( data ) 
                {
                    console.log( data );
                }
            })

            var jField = $(fieldTemplate2);

            $(".komentari").append(jField);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your code. AJAX call should look like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'index.php',
    data: {
        imeBoxa: imeBoxa,
        komentar: komentar
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Pay attention how you construct `data` object to be passed to server. In this example it will pass two POST parameters: `imeBoxa` and `komentar`.

Comment: while I was wondering and wondering, if it would be possible to send the parameters like in the question above, you were faster :-) Perfect answer. One voteup from me.

Comment: I would recommend, to run the fieldTemplate2 things and .append inside of the success:function, so one can make sure, that the comment appears only when successfully stored in db.

Comment: After doing this i try to echo the variable with this
if(isset($_POST['imeBoxa']))
{
    $uid = $_POST['imeBoxa'];
}
echo $uid;
If I use the button and add a comment should it then automatically echo what I wrote @dfsq

Comment: Server should respond with `$uid` in your case.

Comment: It says undefined variable $uid before and after adding a comment, and my comment is shown on the page, javascript does its work.